# Python 3 histogram: how to get counts and bins with plt.hist(), but without displaying the histogram in screen?

Tags: python, histogram

I have a set of data from which I need to extract information. The best way to do this is through a histogram: I would like to obtain a 
For this purpose, I use the function matplotlib.pyplot.hist() which allows me to extract the number of counts **n** and the bins **bins**. I use the function as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

with open('variables/dataHistogram', 'rb') as f:
    data= pickle.load(f)

nBins = 10
n, bins, patches = hist(np.sort(data), nBins, rwidth=0.9, normed = False)
```

I can successfully retrieve the data. My only problem is that, with this method, the histogram is always displayed. And for my purposes, I do not want it to be displayed. Is there a way in which I can extract the data without displaying the histogram ?

As additional information, I am using Spyder for running my code and I am working in Python 3.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `plt.hist`, you can use [numpy.histogram](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html). Example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.random.randint(0, 5, size=10)
>>> x
array([3, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3])
>>> counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(x, bins=3)
>>> counts
array([4, 1, 5])
>>> bin_edges
array([0., 1., 2., 3.])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` for this ([docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html)).

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(0,10,(100))

n, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=10)
```